# Laravel Order Eloquent by relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

For a new project I am working on a webshop. I have products with a one to many relationship with plant details. Plant details have a column price. I need to order the products on the price of the first detail.

If I use a join I get all products ordered by price but I get a new product for each detail relation.

I tried:

```php
$products = $products->get(); 
$products = $products->sortBy(function ($product, $key) { 
    return $product->plantDetails()->first()->price; }); 
    $products = $this->paginate($products, $perPage = 24, true);
}
```

with `$this->paginate` being:

```
public function paginate($items, $perPage = 15, $page = null, $options = []) { 
    $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1); 
    $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items); 
    return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options); 
}
```

but than I don't get the current page in the pagination link. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean, the link of current page from method to render pagination like `$products->render()` only shows nothing, but the other pages shows something like `http://site.test/products?page=2` ?

Comment: $products->links() renders the pagination like expected but the link on the  http://site.test/products page would be http://site.dev/?page=2

Comment: have you tried to remove the 3rd param on `paginate`? Or manually set path to the paginator? `$this->paginate($products, 24)->setPath($request->url());`

Comment: Gonna try that first thing Tuesday morning

Comment: $this->paginate($products, 24)->setPath($request->url()); worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Whay if you use something like that:

```php
$products = $products->sortBy(function ($product, $key) { 
    return $product->plantDetails()->first()->price; })->paginate(24)
```

Paginate will do the get also ...
but I don't understand what you mean by "need to order the products on the price **of the first detail** ?"

first() will return the first object from plantDetails and first()->price price will return exactly the price property of that object.

if you use join method from query builder then you don't need ti use eloquent relationships ..

It could something like that:

```php
$products = DB::table('products')->
join('plantDetails','key','=','key') ->sortBy('price')->paginate(24);
```

where key is the common column between products and plantDetails.

Hope it helps,

Comment: $products = $products->orderBy(function ($product, $key) { 
    return $product->plantDetails()->first()->price; })->paginate(24)
I get strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given error. It's givig this error on paginate() or get(). When I remove the paginate I get a builder object. 
When I use count() on the object I get the correct amount of items